# Change File get contents to curl

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

i have this code (works just fine in localhost)

```
$post_data = array( 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password );
$opts = array( 'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query( $post_data ) ) );

$context = stream_context_create( $opts );

$api_result = json_decode( file_get_contents( $panel_url . "api.php?action=user&sub=info", false, $context ), true );

var_dump ($api_result);
```

but on my server file_get_contents not works, i tried to use curl but i dont know exactly how to change

```
$post_data = array( 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password );
$opts = array( 'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query( $post_data ) ) );

$context = stream_context_create( $opts );


$runfile = $panel_url . "api.php?action=user&sub=info";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $runfile);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $content = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch); 


     $api_result = json_decode( $content );
```

i changed the code to this, works in localhost but on my server i get bool(false)

```
$post_data = array('action'=>'user','sub'=>'info','username' => $username, 'password' => $password );
$opts = array( 'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query( $post_data ) ) );

$context = stream_context_create( $opts );

//$api_result = json_decode( file_get_contents( $panel_url . "api.php?action=user&sub=info", false, $context ), true );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$panel_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);


var_dump ($server_output);
```

Comment: Why isn't `file_get_contents` working? Any error? Is it disabled? cURL could be disabled too then..

Comment: hi @modsfabio i get failed to open stream: Connection refused

Comment: Okay, then check this answer, how to make cURL POST calls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2138534/6485457

Comment: @modsfabio in localhost works fine, on server i get bool(false) - my server is blocking the connection?

Comment: What does `curl_error` say? It's possible that the server blocks the connection, yes. Additionally use `http_build_query($post_data)` for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

Comment: Failed to connect to meuiptv.dyndns.tv port 25461: Connection refused
bool(false) FAILED

Comment: Did you open the port 25461 in your firewall/router? this might be the reason.

Comment: Works fine on my localhost, works fine on my godaddy vps, but not working in a shared hosting account (where are supposed to use the script)

Comment: Do other URLs work ?

Comment: yes i can do file_get_contents(www.google.com) .

Comment: Maybe the hoster does not allow connections to other ports than 80

Comment: You mean my shared hosting right? the one where i put the php script? like i said works in localhost and on my vps, i can connect to the other server and get the json response, but on my shared hosting nothing works.

Comment: Yes, many shared hostings block `cURL` or `file_get_contents` completely. Maybe your hosting blocks connections on other ports than 80